# Instagram API deprecation

Tags: flutter, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have an app that uses Instagram Login to use authenticate the users to the APP and the API which I using for this shown below

**http://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8585&response_type=code**

Is this API is going to deprecate should I move to Instagram basic display API for the same

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what is written [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api), you shouldn't use Instagram Basic Display API for authentication users to login to mobile app, but only to read and display data from Instagram. If your app uses API data to authenticate users, it will be rejected during App Review. You should use rather Facebook Login for authentication.

Comment: yeah but I heard that they are going to deprecate the media API not the authorization API